# Coming up with a self self teaching curriculum in economics?

Tags: self-study, books

I'm a college grad- engineer by trade and wanted to learn about economics. Since I don't know much about the subject I'm not sure exactly how to progress with learning the field. I've started with Microeconomics with Calculus by Perloff and I plan to go through some other book probably with macro, but I'm not exactly where I should go from there, nor do I know the popular learning materials. (game theory? econometrics?) does anyone have suggestions or some sort of roadmap that I could follow to make sure I get a strong foundation in economics sans going back to college? I'm pretty committed and am familiar with some deeper math so difficulty isn't a deterrent (but also keep in mind that I'd be new to the economic concepts).

Comment: Hi :) Glad to hear about your endeavour to learn economics. However, given your position as a grad, I feel you're in the luxury position regarding what you can/should learn, rather than just picking up a book such as Perloff indiscriminately. My advice would be therefore to reduce the very broad topic of economics down to things you would actually like to learn, whether it be monetary policy; public finance; environmental economics; or econometrics (which for an undergrad is basically frequentist cross-sectional statistics). Would be good to hear your thoughts

Comment: I guess if I had to choose areas, I'm definitely interested in finance, health economics, public policy, and econometrics. (Not sure if this narrows things down, haha) I started using the perloff book because I don't really have much of a foundation and figured doing basic micro and macro would give me the necessary prerequisite knowledge before I could advance to other topics.

Comment: I agree, and if I argued on Economics Stack Exchange that you didn't need a strong foundation, then I would deservedly catch some heat.  It therefore pays off to spend some time on microeconomics (the core of all economics), learning about opportunity costs; elasticities; the Law of Compensated Demand;  principal-agent problems etc (this will also help you with health economics, founded on these principles).

Comment: Would you have any recommendations for good materials or textbooks for micro/macro or possibly some of the other topics I listed? The hope is that I'd be able to go through them either sequentially or concurrently.

Comment: Beyond that, the most straightforward recommendation is in terms of econometrics (most texts teach the same thing/some are just better explained). For a broad-spectrum introduction to econometrics (cross-section/time-series/count data), I would argue Wooldridge 'Econometrics: A Modern Approach', and Hill's Principles of Econometrics would be useful. For an all round better book, specifically for time-series and finance, then look at Introductory Econometrics for Finance by Brooks.

Comment: Also, for finance (like really introductory level stuff on financial markets, banks, and central banks), I would recommend Cecchetti 'Money Banking and Financial Markets' (They also have a good blog)

Comment: For very specific stuff on health economics, I would see either the works of authors such as Amy Finkelstein at MIT. Or in terms of less theoretical health economics, the working papers from York University (UK)

Comment: Thanks you for the recommendations.

Comment: Extremely verbose from me. Yet, as you can tell - it is hard to express some texts for 'econ' just as its difficult to recommend one 'math' book or something. Nevertheless, all the best.